# Copy string array index 0 using strcpy

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm attempting to copy one character (string array index 0) to another string array with 30 indexes.

This is a program to generate a username from two string arrays. firstName and lastName.
The format of the username needs to be: jsmith
(e.g: the user enters john smith. the output should be jsmith.)

Here's what I have.

```
void generateName(char firstName[15],char lastName[15])
{
   char userName[30];

   strcpy(userName, firstName[0]);
   strcpy(userName, lastName);

   cout << "Your newly generated username is: " <<userName <<endl;
   getch();
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

Cannot convert 'int' to 'const char *'
Type mismatch in parameter '_src' in call to 'strcpy char *,const char *)'
Parameter 'firstName' is never used

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to use

```
   strcpy(userName, &firstName[0]);
```

instead. Parameters to `strcpy` need to be pointers, you were passing value of first character in the char array instead.

But that call above to `strcpy` will copy the *whole* `firstName` - up to and including the null terminator. If you only want to copy first letter you can do:

```
   memcpy(userName, &firstName[0], 1);
   strcpy(&userName[1], lastName); // append last name
```

Comment: That's fantastic.
Thanks very much for the insight!

Comment: could something like this be done with strcat() also?

Comment: @DohvahQuiin:yes, but I think with strcat destination must be null terminated, whereas in this case it is not. If you initialized user name like this: char userName[30]={0} - then probably, yes. Note: but strcat can't replace what memcpy is doing

Comment: @DohvahQuiin:you are welcome, but strcat can't replace what memcpy is doing

Comment: `username[0] = firstName[0];` is simpler than memcpy

Comment: @M.M:yes but in such case OP can also learn in which cases is memcpy useful

Comment: I never actually thought of that haha. Cheers M.M.
But yes, I've only been doing this for a few weeks, and it's great to learn new stuff. :)